# Allowed memory size exhausted after using a for loop in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this simple code:

```
 for($i = 0; $i <= $this->number_of_pages;$i++)
    {
        $page[$i] = $i + 1;
    }
```

number of pages is always an integer and it is never bigger than 5, however I get this error when number of pages is 1:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   134217736 bytes)

I already fixed it by simply changing `<=` to `<`:

```
  for($i = 0; $i < $this->number_of_pages;$i++)
        {
            $page[$i] = $i + 1;
        }
```

However I am not sure what triggers such error on the first loop. When number of pages is bigger than 1, it gives me one extra loop (as expected). When it is just 1, I get a memory size error.

Anyone bother to explain me why?

Comment: There is something happening outside of this loop

Comment: Well, it looks like $this->number_of_pages was not 1. Try the same printing memory_get_peak_usage() before and after the loop. Another way to test it is using a hardcode 1 instead of $this->number_of_pages

Comment: whats is the result of dump($this->number_of_pages) ?

Comment: @Muthu17 The result is "true". You are onto something. You might want to post this as an answer so everyone can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `$this->number_of_pages` is not an integer, did you try dumping its value or hardcoding a `1` in its place instead?

Answer (score 1):

The function that sets `$this->number_of_pages` gives me `true` instead of `1`. The function itself is from an installed PHP module and I have no control over it so I just set a simple

```
if($this->number_of_pages === "true")
{
$this->number_of_pages = 1;
}
```

I think PHP should not loop at all if a given value is not integer, the fact that it actually worked on the second loop example, but not the first, confused me.